# app with mapkit not running in real device as simulator

Tags: ios, mapkit

i'm developing application (iOS 6.1 , using storyboard) that hold map view (i'm using apple mapkit framework) within it. In the simulator every thing works fine , but when i tried to run the application on real device the app crash when i open the view that holds the map view.
any one knows why that happen?

Comment: check the Xcode deployment target and also check your real device iOS might be some method is Deprecated that not sported longer in your device current iOS

Comment: Please give the exact crash message or stack trace, and the code that is executed when the view is opened.  Using debugging, identify the line on which it crashes.